# error regarding rcu(repository creation utility) installation

Tags: oracle11g

I'm installing RCU(repository creation utility). I was not able to connect to the database. I have given following details on database connection details:

hostname: localhost
port: 1521
service name: XE
I am using sys as my username. I am using oracle 11g database xe. I am getting the following message:

```
UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE WITH DESCRIBED DETAILS CHECK HOSTNAME,PORT AND CHECK IF LISTENER IS UP AND RUNNING
```

I have checked every above detail and my details are right. I have even try to connect with oracle 10g database xe but error was still there. So please if anyone can help me with this problem it would be great.

Thanks,
Tarneet

Answer (score 0):

If the first time that you install the soa environment in a clean OS , probably you will need restart your computer , for the oracle service start correctly.. if you don't have a clean OS probably you need to check your oracle XE installation, if could you can delete and re-install your oracle EX and tray again.